# React-Testing-Library - MatchingFunction interpreted as string

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

`screen.getByText(match: Matcher)` takes a `Matcher` of type `string | RegExp | MatcherFunction` In the case of the latter, the type is `(content: string, element: HTMLElement) => boolean`.

Expectation:
`screen.getByText((content, element) => element.className.includes("my-class") && content.includes("text to search for"));` searches through the DOM for an element of class `my-class` with text `text to search for`

Actual:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: element.className.includes("my-class") && content.includes("text to search for")

It's like the MatcherFunction prototype is being parsed into a string? Could it be because of the lambda syntax?

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax but you could try an explicit `if` statement and then return true or false

Comment: What happens if you just make the function do nothing but `return true`? Or add a "console.log("foo")` in the function. Does that print out? I'm thinking that everything is working as it's supposed to, but the error reporting just stringifies the input argument, whatever it is.

Comment: @AlexWayne it prints out the power set of the DOM (had to change terminal settings to be able to display it all and read the error message) but it does seem to be just error reporting as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as you expect. The function is executing and returning, and your test is failing. The test runner doesn't really have a way to tell you in plain english what your function does, so it simplifies stringifies the thing you searching for (be it a string, regex or function) in the output message about your failure.

You could argue that is a poor developer experience, and you'd be right. But it does look like everything is working as intended.